# Using if statements for GET Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following variable in a php request:

```
myfile.php?location=0&bedrooms=0
```

This is the code I am using to retrieve it (I have indicate the field types because it is the only differnce between how I am handling the requests):

```
$location = intval($_REQUEST['location']);
Field Type = int(11)

$bedrooms = intval($_REQUEST['bedrooms']);
Field Type = tinyint(3)
```

This is how I am handling variables:

```
if ($location == 0)
$ilocation = '2,3,4,5,6,7';
else
$ilocation = $location;

if ($bedrooms == 0)
$ibedrooms = '-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
else
$ibedrooms = $bedrooms;
```

This is how I am using it in my query:

```
Where realty.published = '1' AND locid IN ($ilocation) AND bedrooms IN ($bedrooms)
```

When i have a request such as location=0&bedrooms=1, it works fine but is bedrooms=0 I get no results.

When I change the bedrooms statement to

```
AND bedrooms IN (-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

it works.

Should I have something other than ' ' (single quotes) in the bedrooms if else statement?

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Because `'1,1,2,3,4'` differs from `1,1,2,3,4`. You might need to store them as array

Comment: `AND bedrooms IN ($bedrooms)` shouldn't it be `AND bedrooms IN ($ibedrooms)` ?

Comment: @Déjà vu Thank you so much, I have been changing this all night and missed that.

Comment: Haha no problem. Sometimes all you need is a fresh pair of eyes =]

Answer (score 2):

`AND bedrooms IN ($bedrooms)`

change this to

`AND bedrooms IN ($ibedrooms)`

I know I already asnwered this in the comments,but maybe it's better if you accept my answer as an actual answer so people can see it's answered instead of coming to an unanswered question only seeing it's answered already.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd handle that is like this.

```
if (!isset($_GET['location']) || intval($_GET['location']) == 0){
    $ilocation = '2,3,4,5,6,7';
}
else {
    $ilocation = intval($_GET['location']);
}

if (!isset($_GET['bedroom']) || intval($_GET['bedroom']) == 0){
    $ibedrooms = '-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
}
else {
    $ibedrooms = intval($bedrooms);
}
```

That way, if no value is set in the URL, it default to select everything.